# How to create dataframe of top 5 close words to a particular word lists from a dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, word2vec, gensim

I have a word2vec dictionary which gives a top similar words  to given word.

I want to pass the list of words for which similarity  needs to calculated  from  a file or list

**Input**

```
word_list =['wan,'floor','street']
```

Similarity of these words should be checked against the word2vec dictionary and  similar words to the input word_list must found and written to a dataframe in the below shown format.

```
model.most_similar("wan")

[('wan.', 0.7509685754776001),
 ('want', 0.7326164245605469),
 ('aupuiwan', 0.7161564230918884),
 ('puiwan', 0.7119397521018982),
 ('wanstreet', 0.7096157073974609),
 ('woshing', 0.7046518921852112),
 ('futan', 0.6979573369026184),
 ('won', 0.696295440196991),
 ('fota', 0.6961145401000977),
 ('pul', 0.6921802759170532)]
```

I want create a dataframe with  two columns Word and Similar words.

**Output Dataframe**

```
Word    Similar Words
wan     ('wan.', 'want','aupuiwan','puiwan','wanstreet')
floor   ('fl','flooor','flor','flr','gf')
street  ('st','rosestreet','stret','strt','str')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
words = ['wan', 'floor', 'street']
similar = [[item[0] for item in model.most_similar(word)[:5]] for word in words]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Word': words, 'Similar Words': similar})
```

Comment: I think it should be `zip(*model.similar(word)[:5])`